# bootstrap not display mobile layout inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a site create in bootstrap responsive layout, for some reason, i need to stored data at different server

on my original server I create a page with iframe width:100% height:100% to cover whole page.

My problem is the page doesn't display mobile phone's layout inside of iframe

anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this meta tag inside the head area of your iFrame page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```